# How to disable fast startup permanently

Tags: windows, windows-10

After some updates, Windows has turned on fast startup again.

I want it to never do this again.

How can I teach it to leave this setting alone forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 will not alter this setting due to a windows update, except when the update is actually an upgrade (Anniverary update, and creative update which comes in januari 2017)

Due to the nature of this update, and it creating an almost new windows install, it is impossible to disable this.

Microsoft has mentioned that the new creative update will alter how windows update works to prevent the requirement of big updates like these. So it is likely that you will only have to do it once more.

If you really don't want this, then your only alternative is to disable windows update altogether, but I highly recommend against doing this.

Comment: doing it once more is acceptable, I hope it’ll turn out that way, thanks! (Also for explaining what kind of updates did this)

Comment: NOT once more, today, the updates turned on it again. It is confusing that they can keep other settings while updates but `Fast start up`. I thought the only reason is it is **recommended** or MS not care.

Answer (score 5):

Either add the following to a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power]
;TO UNBLOCK, SWITCH 0 TO 1 IN THE FOLLOWING:

"HiberbootEnabled"=dword:0
```

or make a batch file (.BAT) with:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v HiberbootEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
ECHO The operation completed successfully.
```

and drop it in a startup script/folder/task.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *"after some updates,"* which ones?  I have `Fast Startup` disabled on each Windows 10 machine on my home network, and despite several Windows Updates I haven't seen it enabled again.

Please remember that `Fast Startup` is related to your current power scheme, so there are other variables that could affect it:  changing the power scheme itself, video card driver updates, etc.

Comment: @LPChip explained in his/her answer what kind of update it is. Thanks!